# Change postmeta color in tumblr theme? (CSS)

Tags: css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

Here's a screenshot of my current theme:

[image: blog screenshot]

As you can see, the postmeta at the bottom ("9 minutes ago, notes") are in a really light grey font color that doesn't work with my current background color. I want to make the font darker here's a sample of the code for what a post looks like in this theme:

```
{block:Photo}

    <div class="permalink">
        {block:IfNotDisqusShortname}<a href="{Permalink}">&rarr;</a>{/block:IfNotDisqusShortname}
        {block:Date}{block:IfDisqusShortname}<a href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread"></a>{/block:IfDisqusShortname}{/block:Date}
    </div>

    <div class="photo post">

        {LinkOpenTag}
            <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
        {LinkCloseTag}

        {block:Caption}
            <p>{Caption}</p>
        {/block:Caption}

        <div class="postmeta">{block:Date}<a href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}</a>&nbsp; {/block:Date}<a href="{Permalink}" style="text-transform:lowercase;">{lang:Notes} ({NoteCount})</a></div>

        {block:Tags}
            <a href="{TagURL}" class="tag">
            <span class="pound">#</span>{Tag}</a>&nbsp;
        {/block:Tags}

    </div>

    {block:PostNotes}
        <div>{PostNotes}</div>
    {/block:PostNotes}

{/block:Photo}
```

I added this to my style section:

```
.postmeta a { color: #788ECE; }
```

but it did absolutely nothing. The font color of the postmeta is still the same.

What am I doing wrong?

(Note: this wasn't a theme I built, I'm just trying to customize it. Edit: [Original theme located here](https://www.tumblr.com/theme/3357)).

Comment: Can you share a link for the theme that we can play on it?

Comment: original theme is here: https://www.tumblr.com/theme/3357

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like that:

```
#content .post .postmeta a,
#content .post .postmeta a:link,
#content .post .postmeta a:visited {
    color: #788ECE;
}
```

You can use your browser's inspector to see which styles are assigned to an element.